# Load qmldir from QRC file

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to use the [QML-material library](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material) in a  Qt Quick Application.

But when I try to use the import code it says

> module "Material" is not installed`

```
import Material 0.1
```

I did also try this but that seems not to work:

```
import "modules/Material" as Material
```

`qml.qrc` looks like this, all `qmldir` files are listed:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>modules/Material/qmldir</file>
        <file>modules/Material/Extras/qmldir</file>
        <file>modules/Material/ListItems/qmldir</file>
        <file>modules/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Material/qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or is it not possible to use `qmldir` in `qrc` file?

Comment: Have you tried `engine.addImportPath("qrc:/modules/");` ?

Comment: @GrecKo Yes, but then I get `qrc:///modules/Material/[Name of component].qml:-1 File not found`, forgot to mention that.

Comment: I think you need to add every folder and files to the qrc, not just the qmldirs

Comment: @GrecKo that works, thank you.

Comment: Does someone want to answer it?

Comment: @GrecKo please provide an answer for the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add to the import path the folder where the modules are located.

In this case it's `qrc:/modules/`.

Example:

```
engine.addImportPath( "qrc:///modules" );
```

For a module to work you need to have access to the `qmldir` file, but also all the files referenced in it. So you need to add all the files of the library to the the qrc.

Comment: For an unmodified `qml-material` installed as a git submodule with the `.pri` file you will need to just add: `engine.addImportPath( "qrc:///" );`.