# How can I add the qrc import path for qtquick plugin?

Tags: qt, static, qml, qtquick2

I have built a static Qt library and want to use it deploy my app with a standalone exe. After one day effort, I have known that the qtquick plugin can not be static include into exe.

I need copy some folders in `qml` folder to my exe directory to let the exe can show GUI.

So I want to know which file my exe need, I deleted files in those folders one by one to get it known. The real needed file is just a `plugins.QMLTYPES` file and a `qmldir` file.

And then I found the import path of `QQmlApplicationEngine` can be changed, I output the `QQmlApplicationEngine.importPathList()` and one of paths is just the `qml` folder in Qt installed path. **So I think this is the place where Qt get the search path of `plugins.QMLTYPES` file and `qmldir` file.**

If all I think is correct, I can just copy the folders I need into `qrc` file and use `QQmlApplicationEngine.addImportPath("qrc:/foldersIwant")` to let exe can import what it need on runtime. And because `qrc` is compiled into exe, I can get rid of those folders and let my exe standalone.

But after I do this in my code, app still can not find the files it need even the output of `QQmlApplicationEngine.importPathList()` has the path I put into and I have also checked my path according to [Load qmldir from QRC file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726321/load-qmldir-from-qrc-file).

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qrc:/import/qtquick/"));
    qDebug()<<engine.importPathList();

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is a part of my qrc file

[image]

Is there anything wrong in my deductive？

Further research:

I have add
`engine.addImportPath(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator() + "custom");`

and move all folders into `custom` folders, it can run successfully. And the exe which doesn't have this line can not run with `custom` folder. So I'm wondering the "search" behavior can not be applied to `qrc` file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I get the answer. The result shows all my thoughts are **correct**!

Below is what I had tried and you can just read the end to get the clear steps.

My aim is to compile a standalone qml2 application exe.

In qml1, I can build static Qt library and compile my app with it.

In qml2, the exe can be compiled in same way. But if I run it without Qt-Runtime. It just do not have any window shown on Windows OS (and also show nothing in other OS). I have googled so many informations and found this problem troubled many people since Qt5.0. Now it is Qt5.5, they still haven't repaired it. **So I need copy folders in `QT_INSTALLED_PREFIX/qml` to the root directory of my app to let my app show GUI.**

Althrough the problem will be solved in Qt5.6 (https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/114835/), I can't wait for so long (Qt5.6 will be released at the end of this year). So I decide to package the files by myself.

And I see this question by chance :[Load qmldir from QRC file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726321/load-qmldir-from-qrc-file). It told me that qmldir file can be include into qrc file and the Qml engine can search into those directory. So I think, the QML files can also be included into qrc file.

But the first thing is to find where the qml2 be imported, when I looking into QQmlApplicationEngine's document, I found `addImportPath` function and I told myself that it must be the key of finding the import path. The document tells me everything:

> QStringList QQmlEngine::importPathList() 
>   const Returns the list of 
>   directories where the engine searches for installed modules in a 
>   URL-based directory structure.
>
> For example, if /opt/MyApp/lib/imports is in the path, then QML that 
>   imports com.mycompany.Feature will cause the QQmlEngine to look in 
>   /opt/MyApp/lib/imports/com/mycompany/Feature/ for the components 
>   provided by that module. A qmldir file is required for defining the 
>   type version mapping and possibly QML extensions plugins.
>
> By default, the list contains the directory of the application 
>   executable, paths specified in the QML2_IMPORT_PATH environment 
>   variable, and the builtin Qml2ImportsPath from QLibraryInfo.

After I delete the Qml2ImportsPath in importPathList at runtime, I made a recurrence of the bugs that app do not show any GUI.

And the document of `addImportPath` tells my that it can accept qrc url. So I add all the files in qml just like the question described above. But I still cannot see any GUI.

After several days of thinking. I found the pic I posted in question do not have qmldir files! That's a bug of Qt Creator. I add files using `Add Existing Directory...` and set the filter to *, it still cannot include qmldir file. So I add it into qrc file by xml code.

When I think this time it must work, it just gave me nothing. Just when I was going to give up, a thought occurred : it won't waste me more time to check whether `qrc:/import/qtquick/` is valid.

The result is `false`, there must be a mistake in my qrc usage. I change the prefix and save the qrc with Qt Creator. I found the qrc file cannot use the path like `D:/Qt/Qt-5.5-static/qml/Qt/labs/folderlistmodel/plugins.qmltypes`, it is changed by Qt Creator to `Qt/labs/folderlistmodel/plugins.qmltypes`. At this time, everything works perfect!

Thanks for you reading my story. Here is a conclusion of steps for solving this problem:

1. Copy all folders in QT_INSTALLED_PREFIX/qml to your project folder, it is good to put them under a parent folder not the root folder.
2. Write some code to get all files' relative path except the `.lib` files and
   `.prl` files.
3. Create a new `.qrc` file and include it in `.pro` file. Include all files into this `.qrc` file. I wrote a small program to generate the xml.
4. Add the import path using `addImportPath` method of `QQmlApplicationEngine`.
5. Build and enjoy.