# Unable to load .qml and .js files with qrc

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qresource

I am using [qChart.js](https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js/tree/master) in my QML project, and was able to access the libraries just fine by importing it into QML with

```
import jbQuick.Charts 1.0
```

and adding the resource path by hard-coding the file path

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath("C:\\PathToProject\\qml\\");
```

However, I'd like to deploy my project and can't have a hard-coded path as this will change from user to user. I've attempted to add the files as specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726321/load-qmldir-from-qrc-file), so my qrc now has the following:

[image]

I've now modified my addImportPath statement to the following:

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:///qml");
```

However, when running with `QChart.qml` and `QChart.js` included in the qrc file, I get the following error:

```
qmlcache_loader.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned char const * const QmlCacheGeneratedCode::_qml_jbQuick_Charts_qml_jbQuick_Charts_QChart_js::qmlData" (?qmlData@_qml_jbQuick_Charts_qml_jbQuick_Charts_QChart_js@QmlCacheGeneratedCode@@3QBEB)
qmlcache_loader.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned char const * const QmlCacheGeneratedCode::_qml_jbQuick_Charts_qml_jbQuick_Charts_QChart_qml::qmlData" (?qmlData@_qml_jbQuick_Charts_qml_jbQuick_Charts_QChart_qml@QmlCacheGeneratedCode@@3QBEB)
```

My understanding is that any file referenced in the `qmldir` must also be added to the qrc file, which would be `QChart.qml` and `QChart.js`. I should also add that I am running this in Release mode. In debug mode, I simply get the `module "jbQuick.Charts" is not installed` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having some trouble squinting. I must be getting old. Do consider right-clicking on the errors, copying them, and pasting the errors onto the question inside quote blocks so that we can see them better. :-)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Oops, sorry about that! All fixed, also added a blurb at the bottom that that error only shows in release mode